# Form control issue

Tags: forms, excel, vba

I have an excel spreadsheet that when it's opening, tries to populate a combo box. On my PC, it fails but on another colleague it doesn't.
In design mode, I can click on the combo box with the following formula inside:

```
=EMBED("Forms.ComboBox.1","")
```

The combo box alias is *Combo_bench* and is called (and failed) in the macros like that:

```
Worksheets("Main").Combo_bench.Clear
```

Also when I tried to see the property in design mode, it seems it's the property of an unknown sheet in my workbook. It displays *Sheet01 Worksheet*.

I am not really used to excel macros, so is it something I am missing? I don't understand why it's working on my colleague computer and not mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, most likely it will resolve the issue.

1. Exit all instances of Microsoft Excel.
2. Click Start, type %temp% in the Open box, and then press Enter.
3. In the folder that opens, delete the Excel8.0 folder and the VBE
   folder.
4. Click Start, type %appdata%\microsoft\forms in the Open box, and
   then press Enter.
5. Delete all the files in this folder.
6. Re-start Excel and try your macro

few Steps copied from: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2703186